# Painted texture is not rendering in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-painting

I have added a jpeg file in the texture paint option (tree bark) and it automatically added the texture to my tree. But only in solid mode. If I want to take the internal rendering (no matter which -→ same problem on all) it doesn't render the bark. Only the leaves. I can see the tree trunk itself too, but in cycles it is rendered like in solid mode. I didn't use nodes. Only the external modular tree addon (nodes) Just imagine, you are in solid mode, than the trunk looks like the texture on the right side of the uploaded picture.[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the material node tree that corresponds to the bark covered object? It could be as simple as connecting the texture to a color input socket.

Comment: There is no Texture node (you mean the principled bsdf, right?). The tree itself has no nodes, except the ones from the modular tree addon but these define only how the tree branches etc are created in the editor. But they don't have something in common with the tree texture. How you can see, I went to the Texture paint option and you can see the folder symbol on the right side of the uploaded picture and with that, i added the jpeg file, but it doesn't render in cycles.

Comment: Your Bark is loaded as a Brush texture so you can see it there in the preview window - it is loaded as if you will be painting it onto the surface of your model. to paint, you add an image to paint onto in the Texture Slots panel while in texture paint mode, and then you can paint - but it doesn't automatically connect it to the color input of your shader node, you will need to do that by going to the Shading layout and connecting the image output to the color input of your shader, likely a Principled BSDF. Disconnected, Cycles will not be able to render it.